# What is the difference between marked_for_detroy and destroy associated record in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I understand that the autosave options has to be true and it happens when the parent is save. Is there any other differences? If the autosave is false, the associated record is left and only the link is removed?

Answer (score 0):

If you destroy an associated record and the save fails on the parent record, then you might not be able to recover. The code would have to be enclosed on a transaction to undo the destroy which adds complexity to the code.
Rails and Ruby try to keep things as simple as possible but not simpler ;-)